# [ERROR]: Property 'openPlugin' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'

Tags: deno

```
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'openPlugin' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'.
  return Deno.openPlugin(localPath);
              ~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/x/plugin_prepare@v0.6.0/mod.ts:64:15
```

getting an error like this when server project
Help me anyone have any idea about this.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run Deno with `--unstable` flag.

You can check that [`openPlugin`](https://doc.deno.land/https/raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno/master/cli/js/lib.deno.unstable.d.ts) is currently an unstable API.

---

More info regarding stability [here](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/stability):

> As of Deno 1.0.0, the Deno namespace APIs are stable. That means we
>   will strive to make code working under 1.0.0 continue to work in
>   future versions.
>
> However, not all of Deno's features are ready for production yet.
>   Features which are not ready, because they are still in draft phase,
>   are locked behind the `--unstable` command line flag.